# List append not working

Tags: python, list, append

So I have something similar to this:

```
listPoints=[]
for x in range(100):
    for y in range(10):
        point[0]=x
        point[1]=y
        point[2] = num_cluster
        listPoints.append(point)
print listPoints
```

And when I print listPoints the list only contains the values of the last iteration..what I'm doing wrong? I don't see it

Comment: You're adding the same point reference every time, and changing its contents.  Make new point =[] arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you append `point`, you're not adding a copy of the `point` array -- you're adding a reference to it. So, when you do `listPoints.append(point)`, you're essentially adding the exact same reference to the exact same thing each time. Consequently, when you change `point`, it appears as if every element in `listPoints` also changes.

You can fix the problem by creating a list instead:

```
listPoints=[]
for x in range(100):
    for y in range(10):
        point = [x, y, num_cluster]
        listPoints.append(point)
print listPoints
```

...or by copying it, if you absolutely must:

```
import copy

listPoints=[]
for x in range(100):
    for y in range(10):
        new_point = copy.deepcopy(point)
        new_point[0]=x
        new_point[1]=y
        new_point[2] = num_cluster
        listPoints.append(new_point)
print listPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `point` is a list, you need `append(point[:])` to append a copy of `point` rather than the reference of the list.

If `point` is some other iterables or user defined, you may need module [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to make shallow or deep copy.